# how to display image( as image path ) from database in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, imageview

```
i know how to display images in view page on static,
```

but i am really confused about, display image in view page by image path from database..

the image path is saved in the database using the input type=file is uses and the image name and path save to database.. and how to display that in the view page when call the image path

i don'nt know how to do this..
   any one know the answer please share here..

```
with reguards... prasanth..
```

Comment: What have you got so far? If you know the image path from your database, why don't you simply pass it to your template? Template parameters: `@(path : String)`. Then you get the image like: `<img src="@routes.Assets.at(path)" />`

Comment: <img src="@routes.Assets.at(@post.image)" /> is this possible

Comment: No, the second `@` isn't necessary. This should work: `src="@routes.Assets.at(post.image)"`. (depending on your image path you may or may not need the router, if you don't, you can use `src="@post.image"`)

Comment: ok..when try that the path shows in the view ,not image

Comment: What is the path it shows?

Comment: images/Chrysanthemum.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your image is saved in `public/images/` and the path saved in your database is `images/image.jpg`, you can simply pass the path to your view and use the router to resolve the image:

```
@(path : String)

<img src="@routes.Assets.at(path)" />
```

In the end this will give you the following HTML:

```
<img src="/assets/images/image.jpg" />
```

(you can verify this by looking at the source  code of the generated HTML page, `ctrl - u` in Firefox) 
The `assets` folder is where Play puts all the images from the `public/images` directory.

Comment: @PrasanthAR How to pass what in url?

Comment: Sorry that's my question How to pass image path in url